# Cannot register device id to parse.com after upload it in App Store

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So i used parse.com for push notification.

The problem:

I have tested my apps in Provisioning profile '**development**' and '**ad hoc**' before, and it work (receive notification & it can register my device id to parse.com).

But after uploaded to the appstore, my apps doesn't work (cannot receive any notif & register the device id to parse)

Please help me !
Thankss!!

In "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
[Parse setApplicationId:@"---------------------"
              clientKey:@"---------------------"];

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    // use registerUserNotificationSettings
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    // use registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    UIRemoteNotificationType myType= UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myType];
}#else
   // use registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
#endif
   return YES;
}
```

in application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

in applicationDidBecomeActive:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
        currentInstallation.badge = 0;
        [currentInstallation saveEventually];
    }
}

- (BOOL) pushNotificationOnOrOff
{
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
        return ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]);
    } else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
        return (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert);
    }
}

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application   didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:   (UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString   *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to subscribe to a channel.

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"global" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```